Translate this Idiom to Korean "The hardest things in life are the most rewarding"
Can someone Translate this Idiom to Korean "The hardest things in life are the most rewarding"?
What is their version of the idiom? Papago seems little off, thank you

There is not a good word for word translation that will sound correct.
However 고생 끝에 낙이 온다 means, "After suffering comes happiness."
고생 - suffering / hardship
끝에 - at the end of / after
낙이 - happiness / joy/ pleasure /enjoyment / delight felt in life
온다 - come
